# global.asa where does it belong?

Tags: asp-classic

I'm moving some ASP code from one server to another. The location names are slightly different and I suspect that now the "global.asa" isn't getting called properly. The location is in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myApp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that "myApp" in IIS is defined as an application.  I would also check the .Net application mappings to make sure .Net is handling your requests.

Answer (score 1):

It belongs in the root folder of your application. Also make sure that that folder is a application in the IIS manager. There is a textbox for application name, and right next to it a button "Create", if the folder isn't already an application.

Answer (score 0):

The global.asa should be in the root of your virtual directory.  Note that global.asa is used by asp not asp.net.

You can generally tell by looking at IIS Manager whether or not your directory is a virtual directory as it will not look like a yellow folder.  If it does look like the typical yellow folder, right click the parent "Default Web Site" or whatever, and choose new virtual directory. 
Alternatively, the global.asa can go in the root of the Web.  Which is typically C:\inetpub\wwwroot if you are using the "Default Web Site"

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, I want to keep in a subdirectory. Apparently, you have to designate that directory as an application. Here's a link that describes how:

http://www.calcaria.net/ASP/2006/04/globalasa-file-doesnt-work.html

Generally, I'm against the idea of files which are called auto-magically and not referred to in the code. If you are a noob like me, you can go off the rails for a while, before you track it down. I just lost a couple of hours on this silliness.